# catch global appcrash on delphi program at leaving

Tags: delphi

My delphi program sometimes crashes when closing.
(he's designed to close itself with an instruction)

My goal is simply to bypass that Crash error (so the program closes itself WITHOUT displaying the nasty error message box that prevents the application to close).

I guess I need a global exception handler for that.
I know I should track the bug that raises that error, but I need to make something quick&dirty so just preventing that error message box is a valid solution for now.

Any clue is welcome.

```
  Nom d’événement de problème:  APPCRASH
  Nom de l’application: AutomateBuilder.exe
  Version de l’application: 1.0.0.0
  Horodatage de l’application:  2a425e19
  Nom du module par défaut: KERNELBASE.dll
  Version du module par défaut: 6.1.7601.17965
  Horodateur du module par défaut:  506dbe50
  Code de l’exception:  0eedfade
  Décalage de l’exception:  0000c41f
  Version du système:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.1296.17
  Identificateur de paramètres régionaux:   1036
  Information supplémentaire n° 1:  c360
  Information supplémentaire n° 2:  c3603bb720f34381cd4463c13e515373
  Information supplémentaire n° 3:  04ba
  Information supplémentaire n° 4:  04ba20d4fba8ec9ad3a49cccf38783e
```

Comment: I once wrote a stupid little invisible tool which scans for these error messages and if it found one, it presses the 'OK' button.

Comment: You don't give any details about how you are closing the app, and why it results in exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

see SetErrorMode

> Controls whether the system will handle the specified types of serious
>   errors or whether the process will handle them.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680621%28v=vs.85%29.aspx